Any technique for preheating Iframe component (React)
In my scenario, I am working with two web pages page1 and page2. On page2, there is a component called  that render iframe, and this process can take some time to complete. To improve the overall user experience, I aim to prefetch, preheat or prerender this component while the user is still on page1. So that when the user navigate to page2, the  is ready. It would be great if anyone could share any technique in order to achieve this.
